# PHP Call to undefined function with NameSpace

Tags: php, function, class, namespaces

I start coding with use "namespace".

**Core.php:**

```
namespace Language;
    class LanguageCore {
        private $langCode = "pl";
        private $language;
        public function __construct(){
            if(file_exists("lang/".substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2).".php"))
                $this->langCode = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
            require_once "lang/".$this->langCode.".php";
            $this->language = new language();
        }
        public function gt($index = null)
        {
            return "its work";
        }
    }
```

and one work very well

**Index.php:**

```
  require_once 'core.php';
  use Language\LanguageCore as Lang;

  $lang = new Lang();
  echo $lang->gt(); // return "its work"
```

but when I tried to add "use function" I had a fatal error

```
  require_once 'core.php';
  use Language\LanguageCore as Lang;
  use function Language\LanguageCore\gt as _;

  $lang = new Lang();
  echo _(); // return error
```

error message:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Language\LanguageCore\gt()
```

What am I doing wrong?

regards!

EDIT:
I need to have this function in a class because I'm using a class variable in this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access the gt method from your LanguageCore class, you will need to call it in this way:

```
require_once 'core.php';
use Language\LanguageCore as Lang;

$lang = new Lang();
echo $lang->gt();
```

This is because gt is a method of your LanguageCore class. So when initiating this class you will need to call the method on the object that is stored into the $lang variable.

If you want to use the `use function` syntax. You will have to move the method out of the class as in this example :

```
namespace Language {

function gt($index = null)
{
    return "its work";
}

class LanguageCore {
    private $langCode = "pl";
    private $language;

    public function __construct()
    {
        ...
    }

    public function gt($index = null)
    {
        return "its work";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Okay, but when i need to have this func in class, because i'm using class variable in to this func, Can I do anything to get the desired effect?

Comment: Not possible to use "use function" on a class method.